# Aligning road names in a row in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am trying to align road names in a row, or column as much as possible in QGIS. I know it can be done in Adobe Illustrator with a mapping plugin, but I don't have the $$ for that.

I tried something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87793/shp-file-left-right-label-alignment-issue-in-qgis-2-0-1-dufour) but it didn't didn't seem to help.

This is an example: [image]

It doesn't need to be exactly like that, but I'd like to do something similar.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

(1) Draw a line as the guide for the label position.

In this example this `guideline` layer has an id field `"fid"` with only one value (`1`).

[image]

(2) Go to the `Layer properties | Labels | Placement`.

There you will find `Data defined | Coordinate X and Y`. Select **Edit** from each pull-down menu.

[image]

(3) Give an expression:

`x`: `x(intersection($geometry, geometry(get_feature('guideline', 'fid', '1'))))`

`y`: `y(intersection($geometry, geometry(get_feature('guideline', 'fid', '1'))))`

[image]

(4) As the final step, please hide the guideline. Select the guideline layer and change  the symbology to `No Symbols`.

[image]

Comment: I'm always amazed at what we can do with the different functions/expressions. Another use case to remember!

Comment: @GabrielC. I cannot agree with you more. I'm so grateful to QGIS Dev team for these amazing expressions!

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! 1 more question and I'll definitely mark that as my answer. How do I then add a second line for if my roads go into another county, and need different names, or to do the roads that run the other way?

Comment: I know it could be done by making a duplicate of the road layer, showing only labels, and not symbology, and marking the labels for "('guideline', 'fid', '2'). but I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks @TroyBuerge But I am sorry I cannot think of any better solution than you have in your comment.